# Evaluating simple algebraic function within restricted range

Tags: recursion

Okay I get that this should be simple but I'm at my wit's end. Very simple problem:

I have an expression

```
f[x_] := 5 x + 1
```

wherein `x` can be any whole number $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, $\dots$

I want the list of all possible values up to/including that at the maximum point of the function's allowed range of output.

Obviously we're just incrementing the prior value from and including 1 (when `x = 0`) until the next incrementation would exceed the maximum value allowed by the restricted range (not the same as the range function in *Mathematica* of course; I'm talking about the domain/range concepts of functions generally), which I want to be able to assign as a variable (let's say `m`).

If I were to say the maximum (inclusive) value of the range of the function `f` is `m = 30`, then my output should be a list of all values from and including 1, to and including the last that's less than or equal to `m = 30`, as below. Please help me write the proper code for this.

Expected output: `{1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26}` (more than this would exceed 30 so it terminates).

We could use `While` or `Do`, but the important point is I can't limit the evaluation based on number of increments because I won't necessarily know how many will be required, only how large a maximal value that the final output must be less than (e.g., `m = 30`).

Comment: Maybe `MaxValue[{5 x + 1, 5 x + 1 <= 30}, x \[Element] Integers]`

Comment: That would work if I only needed the maximum value, but I need the list of all values within the range in order, so 26 needs to be preceded by 1,6,11,16,21

Comment: I see. Do you want it only over over integers? May I assume that the functions `f` are not something ill or extremely complex numerically?

Comment: I just need it over whole numbers (x=0,1,2,3...) but such that f returns output values up to / including some maximal m such as 30, so m implies the literal range of the function is y = [ 0 , 30 ]. The only thing I intend to modify depending on situation is how much I'm multiplying x by (or equivocally, how much we're incrementing the function, in this case 5).

Comment: `f[x_] := 5 x + 1;
m = 30;
x = 0;
Flatten@Rest@Reap[While[f[x] <= m, Sow[f[x]]; x++]]` ?

Comment: I think you did it :) Thank you. Reap & Sow?! haha

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to upvote and accept the naswer if you find it useful.

Comment: `Solve[5 x + 1 == y && 0 <= y <= 30, y, Integers]`

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the function

```
f[x_] := 5 x + 1
```

and set the maximum value `m` that it is not allowed to exceed:

```
m = 30;
```

The domain of `x` is `Integers`; `Sow` and `Reap` will gather the instances fulfilling the condition `f[x]<=m` until `While` is executed:

```
x = 0;
Flatten@Rest@Reap[While[f[x] <= m, Sow[f[x]]; x++]]
```

> {1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26}

**A different approach** would be to find the maximal value of `f[x]`, the `Solve` to get a corresponding `xmax`, and finally make a suitable `Table`:

```
max = MaxValue[{f[x], f[x] <= m}, x \[Element] Integers]
```

> 26

```
xmax = x /. First@Solve[f[x] == max, x]
```

> 5

```
Table[f[x], {x, 0, xmax}]
```

> {1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26}

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_] = 5 x + 1;

f[x] /. Solve[{f[x] <= 30, x >= 0}, x, Integers]

(*  {1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26}  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ArgMax`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArgMax.html):

```
f[x_] := 5 x + 1

f /@ Range[ArgMax[{f[x], f[x] <= 30}, x, Integers]]
(* {6, 11, 16, 21, 26} *)
```